# How do I check for file encryption in VBA (MSAccess)

Tags: file, ms-access, vba, encryption

I'm building a form that moves files from one location to another based on data within the DB, and it works as long as the source file is not encrypted (green filename in windows explorer) and as long as the destination file does not exist.

So I'm trying to create the following:

```
Public Function isEncrypted(file As String) As Boolean
    Dim info As System.IO.FileInfo
    info = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(file)

    Dim attr As System.IO.FileAttributes
    attr = info.Attributes

    isEncrypted = ((attr And System.IO.FileAttributes.Encrypted) > 0)
End Function
```

But it doesn't run at all. Anyone have experience with this, or is there an easier way to check for encryption? Access hangs and crashes if I try to rename & move an encrypted file.

Comment: How can you use `System.IO.FileAttributes` in VBA code?  That Dim statement causes a compiler error on my system.

Comment: To follow up on @HansUp's comment: the code you have written is VB.NET code; VBA is based on VB 6, which is an entirely different animal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, there is no way that the vb.net code is going to compile in access.  You will most likely need to use a system call from win32 to get the file attributes.  The FileSystemObject (Scrrun.dll 'Windows Scripting Runtime') object will not work either as it's enumeration will not tell you if the file is encrypted.  Here is a windows API function you can use to determine if the file is encrypted or not.

```
Public Enum FileAttribute
'uses VBA Hex Notation
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY = &H1
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN = &H2
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM = &H4
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = &H10
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE = &H20
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE = &H40
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = &H80
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY = &H100
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE = &H200
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT = &H400
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED = &H800
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE = &H1000
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED = &H2000
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED = &H4000
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL = &H10000
End Enum

Private Declare Function GetFileAttributes Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetFileAttributesA" (ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long

Public Sub Test()

    Dim fileTestPath As String
    Dim attributes As Long

    fileTestPath = "C:\yourfile.txt"

    attributes = GetFileAttributes(fileTestPath)

    'uses bitwise AND calculations to determine values
    If (attributes And FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE) Then Debug.Print "Archive"
    If (attributes And FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED) Then Debug.Print "Compressed"
    If (attributes And FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE) Then Debug.Print "Device"
    If (attributes And FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) Then Debug.Print "Directory"
    If (attributes And FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED) Then Debug.Print "Encrypted"
    If (attributes And FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) Then Debug.Print "Hidden"
    If (attributes And FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL) Then Debug.Print "Normal"
    If (attributes And FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED) Then Debug.Print "Not Content Indexed"
    If (attributes And FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE) Then Debug.Print "Offline"
    If (attributes And FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY) Then Debug.Print "ReadOnly"
    If (attributes And FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT) Then Debug.Print "ReparsePoint"
    If (attributes And FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE) Then Debug.Print "SparseFile"
    If (attributes And FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM) Then Debug.Print "System"
    If (attributes And FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY) Then Debug.Print "Temporary"
    If (attributes And FileAttribute.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL) Then Debug.Print "Virtual"

End Sub
```